# Please help me to solve this ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I want to solve this ode in matlab numerically. A,B,C,D,E,F,G[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlpb3.jpg) are constant values. I think that in matlab bvp4c command can solve this ode. I studied matlab help related to the bvp4c command but I could not understand how to write it for this problem. I would be appreciated if any one could help me and write me the commands in matlab. The picture of ode is presented below.
Regards,
Nima Sina

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing your problem, I will show how to solve a problem of the same size. Consider the BVP:

$$\frac{d^6 y}{dx^6} + 2 \frac{d^5 y}{dx^5} + 3 \frac{d^4 y}{dx^4} + 4 \frac{d^3 y}{dx^3} - 2 \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} + 7 \frac{dy}{dx} - 5y = 1 \\
\frac{d^5y}{dx^5}(0) + \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}(0) + y(0) = 0 \\
y(0)=0 \\
\frac{dy}{dx}(0)=0 \\
y(2)=0 \\
\frac{dy}{dx}(2) = 0 \\
\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}(2)=0.
$$

Then you can do the following:

```
odefun=@(x,y) [y(2);y(3);y(4);y(5);y(6);1 + 5*y(1) - 7*y(2) + 2*y(3) - 4*y(4) - 3*y(5) - 2*y(6)];
bcfun=@(ya,yb) [ya(6)+ya(3)+ya(1);ya(1);ya(2);yb(1);yb(2);yb(4)];
solinit=bvpinit([0;2],zeros(6,1))
sol = bvp4c(odefun,bcfun,solinit);
```

Comment: @ Ian
Thanks for responding my question but it seems that still there are some flaws
1- The true command is bvp4c not bv4pc.
2- As the order is 6 it is essential to define 6 boundary values in the bcfun.
3-After defining 6 boundary values still an error occurs. And this is the error:

Too many input arguments.
Error in bvparguments (line 105)
    testODE = ode(x1,y1,odeExtras{:});
Error in bvp4c (line 130)
    bvparguments(solver_name,ode,bc,solinit,options,varargin);

I would be thankful if you could correct your commands for a 6th order ode than runs without any error
Regards

Comment: @Nima Try it now. (Note that I also forgot to make my odefun take an x argument because it didn't use it.) Given what you wrote there you might still get an error if the "odefun" that you pass to bvp4c takes a third argument. It can't, so you may need to make a "closure" to fix that.